# django InlineFormsets errors reporting with formset error list being empty

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a strange error on creation using Django inline formsets.

Django is reporting formset errors, so it doesn't finish the creation.

Also I tested `is_valid` and it returns true. What is wrong ?

but if I check them there is nothing in the dictionary of errors:

1.

```
 {{formset.errors}}
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

2.

```
{%  if formset.errors %}
        {% for error  in formset.errors %}
            error {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
{%  endif %} 

{}
```

---

I think I understand the issue:

```
{%  if formset.errors %} even if I have [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}] will pass.
```

If I use `{%  if not formset.errors %}`, will block also when I have real errors.

Checking if a list is empty is not working, because is not really empty, it has empty dictionaries.

I can use a loop inside the form list to check the dictionaries, but going this for each field or form/formset I don't see it as a good option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, check that the formset is bound.

```
formset.is_bound
```

If you haven't bound the formset to any data, then it won't have any errors but it will never be valid.

Secondly, make sure you are calling the `is_valid` method

```
formset.is_valid()
```

Finally, note that `formset.errors` returns a list of dictionaries containing the errors for each form. There is also `formset.non_form_errors()`, whic returns errors that do not belong to a particular form.

Comment: is_valid is called and returns true, but it is in form. I'm doing this check in the templates to show the errors. How can I check is bound in the template ?

Comment: If you are definitely calling `is_valid()` then the form is bound - you use `formset.is_valid` in your question so that wasn't clear. It would help if you included some more information (e.g. formset class, view, full template) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was stuck for hours trying to figure out why my formset was not valid when `formset.errors` returned an empty list. Turns out the cause lies in `formset.non_form_errors()`